# Am I wrong in wanting to roll my own Authenticate / Authorize system given the following requirements?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, authorization, db4o, turbine

In my pet project I want to have a user system with the following requirements:

- It needs to work with [Db4o](http://www.db4o.com/) as a persistance model
- I want to use DI (by means of [Turbine](http://mvcturbine.codeplex.com/)) to deliver the needed dependencies to my user model
- It needs to be easy to plug in to asp.net-mvc
- It needs to be testable without much hassle
- It needs to support anonymous users much like SO does
- I want Authentication and Authorization separated (the first can live without the second)
- It needs to be safe

I'm aware I'm putting a few technologies before functionalities here, but as it is a pet project and I want to learn some new stuff I think it is reasonable to include them as requirements.

Halfway in rolling my own I realized I am probably suffering some [NIH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_Invented_Here) syndrome.
As I don't really like how needlessly complex the existing user framework in asp.net is, it is actually mostly only all the more complicated stuff regarding security that's now giving me some doubts.
Would it be defendable to go on and roll my own? If not how would you go about fulfilling all the above requirements with the existing IPrinciple based framework?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you want to do is roll your own Custom .NET Membership Provider.

It will allow you to use the built-in ASP.NET Authentication<strike>/Authorization</strike> attribute<strike>s</strike> on your Controller Actions while giving you complete control over the implementation inside the provider (which will allow you to code it to meet the requirements stated above).

Direct from MSDN...

[Implementing a Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link. That might be a solution that allows me have my cake and eat it too.

Comment: @boris That definitely looks interesting. Might be something to take a look at as I'm guessing it misses out on a couple of your requirements. The fact that it needs to be run in a full trust environment might make me hesitate if you ever want to distribute the app...

Comment: The problem is that however you implement it, if it's going to need db4o, it will always be full trust. Unless I host the db4o somewhere different (my own machines?) I think it will be inevitable.

Comment: as a side note: what do you mean with Authentication/Authorization attributes? As far as I'm aware they are one and the same in the current architecture (that's one of the things I'm not 100% comfortable with)

Comment: They're rolled in to the same attribute, yes. Sorry for the confusion. The two aspects are handled seperately by your provider though. An empty [Authorize] just states that the user needs to be Authenticated to call the Action. Provider Roles in the attribute is how you handle Authorization. Personally, I think this makes thing look cleaner and easier to understand in the code base (you don't have anybody having Authorize without a matching Authenticate, etc.)

Comment: You are probably right. From an architectural POV I would prefer them separated, but usage would dictate them to be together.

Answer (score 1):

If you go ahead and create your own custom solution, you will have a better idea of how difficult it is and what features you want. This will help you to evaluate off-the-shelf solutions for future projects.

OTOH, spending time developing functionality that is already readily available means you won't be spending that time working on the major functionality of your project. Unless authentication and authorization are a major component of your project, you might consider investing your time, and expanding your knowledge, in another area.

Comment: Seeing it is a pet project, "learning" is the major functionality ;)
I'm using the existing framework at work already and I find it too generic in most cases. I understand it is meant to be one-size-fits all, but for some reason it never feels snug to me.

Comment: I agree with you about the Membership provider being too generic. Not only that, I have found it very difficult to customize. I would avoid it on any non-trivial project. I'd still evaluate whether learning more about authentication and authorization is worth more to you than learning about something else. If you haven't done much with it, this is a great opportunity to learn and experiment.

Answer (score 1):

I think you recognize where the thin parts in your consideration are: namely in that you've included how to do what you're doing as motive in why you're doing it and the NIH (funny: I'd never seen that before) issue.

Putting those aside, your provider is something that you could potentially reuse and it may simplify some of your future efforts.  It should also serve to familiarize you further with the issue.  As long as you understand the ASP.NET framework so you can work with it too if you need to (and aren't specialized such that you don't know what you're doing if you're not using your tool) then I believe you've already crafted your defense.

As DOK mentioned, be cautious that you're not rolling your own here to avoid a larger task at hand in whatever your other functionality is.  Don't let this be a distraction: it should be something your application really needs.  If it's not, then I'd lean towards focusing on your software's core mission instead.

Answer (score 1):

I too am working on a pet Project using ASP.net MVC and db4o and did the same thing, so you're at least not alone in going down that route :). One of the biggest reasons for me to start playing around with db4o as persistence layer is that especially authorization on field level (i.e I'm allowed to see Person A's first name but not Person B's first name) is though to achieve if you're forced into complex SQL statements and an anemic domain model.

Since I had complex authorization needs that needed to be persisted (and synchronized) in both db4o and Solr indexes I started working on rolling out my own, but only because I knew up front it was one of the key features of my pet project that I wanted 100% control over.

Now I might still use the .Net Membership provider for authentication but not (solely) for authorization of objects but only after i POC'd my authorization needs using my own.

Comment: What do you mean with POC'ing authorization needs? All them TLA's ;)

Comment: My bad, damn us programmers and our TLA's (i had to google TLA btw (by the way) ;)). POC == proof of concept.

Comment: Damn, should have figured that one out. Or maybe a quick lmgtfy would've sufficed ;)